# Explicitly setting the current directory (pipeline shell)

Tags: pwd

SHORT: How do I explicitly set the current working directory?

LONG: So I have 52 programs daisy chained together.  I have a shell script pipeline that works great.  Only problem is I can only run it if I cd into the directory with the files and run it.  Some of the sub-programs do not have a mechanism that allows me to explicitly set output directories.  They dump everything into the current working directory.  This is fine if you are running 1 instance of this pipeline, but not so great if you are trying to process a dozen data-sets one after another.  I know I can get the current working directory with:

echo $PWD

But how do I set it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current dirctory for individual programs in your pipeline without affecting the other program in your pipeline like this:

```
PWD=path1 command1 && PWD=path2 command2
```

In general, you can set any environment variable using that syntax.  Here is a real example I tried in bash:

```
$ PWD=/home ./test.rb && PWD=/ ./test.rb 
Running in /home
Running in /
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,  How come I can't get that to work with simple linux commands like "PWD=/data1/test mkdir dir2".... that doesn't change where dir2 is produced.

Comment: also, why can't i formated 3rd tier comments?
double space  
html markup <br>
more markup </br>

Comment: You can format comments; for example, type \`code\` and it will look like `code`.

Comment: Hm, I don't know why it doesn't work for `mkdir`.  There must be another mechanism for setting the current working directory other than the PWD environment variable.